# separate categories on wordpress post meta

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I run this blog www.livinglikeastartup.com with WordPress and I have a problem with categories in the post meta. As you can see, categories sometimes are attached one to each other. I can't understand why.

I bought a theme with no support for such things (grrr). here's the code I supposed should be modified.

```
add_action( 'cmb2_init', 'cmb2_story' );
function cmb2_story() {
$prefix = '_tribe_';

$story_cats_cmb = new_cmb2_box( array(
        'id'            => 'story_category_metabox',
        'title'         => __( 'Story Category', 'cmb2' ),
        'object_types'  => array( 'page', ),
        'show_on'      => array( 'key' => 'page-template', 'value' => 'story-template.php' ),
        'context'       => 'normal',
        'priority'      => 'high',
        'show_names'    => true
) );

$categories = get_categories(array("hide_empty"=>0));
$options = array();
foreach($categories as $category){
    $options[$category->term_id] =  $category->name;
}
$story_cats_cmb->add_field( array(
  'id'         => $prefix . 'story_category',
  'type'       => 'select',
        'options'        => $options
));
}
```

thanks to everyone who will help!

Comment: Are you selecting more than one category for certain posts? If so, your theme is displaying all categories side by side, which is standard WordPress functionality. Do you want only one category to be displayed? If so, which? And if your not selecting more than one category, take for instance your post "Start Easy. The Hard Way". What category did you in fact select?

Comment: I would like to show cat1 "and" cat2 in home and category page as it is in post page

Comment: I see. But anyway, I'm pritty sure this isn't the code to be editing. We need to be looking at the place in your code where the posts are being echoed out.